# How to update Textbox and Image value when dropdown value change in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to change value of Textbox and Image when dropdown value changes. Currently, I am using `Json` to get respective value from database.
I am stuck now. I do not have an idea how to append these values.

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult UpdateContent(ViewModel model)
        {          
                var Getdata = context.Emp.Where(x => x.Position == model.Position).FirstOrDefault();     
                 model.Title= Getdata.Title;
                 model.Link= Getdata.Link;
                 model.FilePath= Getdata.FilePath;
                return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                      
        }
```

Script

```
 function UpdateContent() {
            var formdataEdit = $('#Editform');
            var data = formdataEdit.serialize();
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateContent", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {                      
                        $('#Title').val(data);
                        $('#Link').val(data);
                        var filepath =  $('#FilePath').val(data);
                        $('#aImage').attr('src', filepath);
                    }
                    else {
                        var message = data.message;
                        alert(message);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
success: function (data) {
                   if (data) {                      
                        $('#Title').val(data.Title);
                        $('#Link').val(data.Link);
                        var filepath = data.FilePath;
                        $('#aImage').attr('src', filepath);
                    }
                    else {
                        var message = data.message;
                        alert(message);
                    }

                }
```

When the ajax call is performed, the model returned by the controller is parsed into the data parameter by jQuery, and the data properties names are the same as the model properties names.